Is there a way to modify the POST data in an extension now?
I'm testing the webRequest API for extension. Specifically, I want to modify the data in the request body before sending it to the server.
manifest.json
{
  "description": "Demonstrating webRequests",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "webRequest-demo",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "*://localhost/*"],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}

background.js
function changebody(requestDetails) {
    if(requestDetails.method=="POST") {
        console.log("requestDetails:", requestDetails);
        requestDetails.requestBody.formData["textarea1"]=["hello world"];
    }
    return  requestDetails;

}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  changebody,
  { urls: ["*://localhost/*"]},
  ["blocking","requestBody"],
);

<html>
<head><title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="test.php" method="post">
    <textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1">test</textarea>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>

But the code does not work. The data sent to the server remains unchanged. I searched here and got this post: Firefox Extension - Filter & modify HTTP POST data using onBeforeRequest which says it is not possible to modify the request body due to a bug, and this post: How to modify request bodies by chrome extension which recommends a Chrome extension written in Typescript.
I would like to know that if it's still impossible to modify the POST data with a Firefox extension now? Or, there's a new way to do this nowadays? I read carefully about the detailed information of the bug and know the complexity of fully fixing the bug. But I don't care the full fix. I just need a partially fixed version, the one that can modify a bit data in a not long request body.

ManifestV3 removed webRequestBlocking for normal extensions that aren't installed via policy. 1) Report it in https://crbug.com. 2) Try listening to submit event in the content script. 3) To intercept more cases override HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit in the MAIN world.

@woxxom Thanks for the information. I'll try that. The trouble is I would have to analyze the DOM to find the nodes I'll modify if I do it in the content script, while I can easily locate the data to be modified in the POST request body in background script.

No need for nodes: window.addEventListener('submit', e=>e.preventDefault(), true) where true means the "capture phase" i.e. your listener sees it before any other normal listeners. In your real code you probably won't need preventDefault, it's here just to show that it actually works.

I wonder if this code might work in Firefox on something other than localhost as the bug you've linked is about future improvements, AFAICT. Maybe localhost is bugged. Don't forget to add the site to permissions.
